# Javascript loading tabs, only works 50% of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble making a tab active when loading the page. This is the page: http://copy.ateo.dk/kollekolle/

The tabs are the ones in the top, called "Billeder" and "Kort". Every so often, when the page loads, it will not make the first tab active, and just show the content of the two tabs on top of each other.

Here is the JS fiddle - however this does not show the error, but the code can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/eromreve/QgD6N/

```
<?php echo $somecodehere or it wont let me submit jsfiddle ?>
```

The error only occurs maybe about 50% of the time.

Best Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The believe at some cases the JavaScript executes before the document load. The JavaScript that is responsible for activating the Tab it needs to be wrapped with Document Ready.

```
$(function() {
  //Code that is responsible for making the tab active/inactive
});
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi hasanavi,

Thanks for your answer - at the begining of the document i initialise $(document).ready(function() { //code }); so basicly i guess all my code is run after the document is loaded, however, this still is not solving the problem. You can check out the entire code of js here: http://copy.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/js/default.js - the function for the tabs is called "function tabs(tabId)"

Comment: Hi again hasanavi,

So this sort of worked, i made the document ready within a document ready function, and this seems to have solved the problem somewhat :)